# Why I am getting Tomcat startup error with java 11

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, java-11

I have a project in java 8 which I am trying to migrate to Java 11. I faced issue with sun.security.x509. That got resolved by adding below code in pom

```
    <compilerArgs>
        <arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>java.base/sun.security.x509=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
```

When I am do tomcat start after maven build, I get below error,

```
Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.annotation.Resource.lookup()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I can see few posts on StackOverflow related to this error.

[javax.annotation classes and Java 11 JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855335/javax-annotation-classes-and-java-11-jdk)

[How to remove a maven lib (jsr250-api-1.0.jar) from the plugin classpath (jetty:run)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607814/how-to-remove-a-maven-lib-jsr250-api-1-0-jar-from-the-plugin-classpath-jetty)

[Access `sun.security.x509` in JDK 11 without modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149455/access-sun-security-x509-in-jdk-11-without-modules)

I dont see jsr250-api lib in my target folder.
I tried all of those but no luck. I am not sure what is wrong here.

Please let me know if you have any idea about this error.

Comment: What version of Tomcat and Maven are you using? What kind of project?

Comment: @aled - Maven 3.8.1 and Tomcat 9.0.41

Comment: I feel, this is class loading issue. Is there any way to check which jar is loading javax.annotation.Resource ? I tried Tomcat Fine level logging but that doesnt tell anything about jar.